# Problems with a simple URL rewrite (htaccess)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I can't get a simple htaccess rewrite to work.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /?id=$1 [L]
```

I went to `mysite.com/?id=blah` expecting to end up on `mysite.com/blah.html`. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how htaccess works. It doesn't re-write the URL visible to the user, rather it looks more like an invisible re-direct.

I'm not even sure what that rewrite in the question is supposed to be doing... BUT, for explanation purposes, let's say you wanted a user to be able to go to:

```
mysite.com/blah/
```

but you wanted the server to see it as:

```
mysite.com/index.php?page=blah
```

You could do this:

```
RewriteRule blah/ index.php?page=blah
```

The user would ALWAYS SEE WHAT THEY TYPED IN. It's not going to change the URL in the browser bar (that would be a header redirect or something, which is completely different and not really related).